# Disable or Mute Trash Sound

Tags: finder, preferences, trash

How can I disable the sound when deleting a file from Finder in OS X Mountain Lion?

I do not see any specific mention of it under System Preferences or Finder Preferences. I don't want to disable other sounds; just that one.

Comment: Are you using Mountain Lion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The sound file for moving an item to the trash is located here:

Go to your HD > System > Library > Components > CoreAudio.component (right click and choose "Show Package Contents") > Contents > SharedSupport > SystemSounds > dock > "drag to trash.aif"

This "drag to trash.aif" is the sound file responsible for the audio effect.

Back up the current file just incase and replace it with a silent one (a quick google search will do - you might need to get the silent file as mp3 and then convert it to aif).

You may need to restart for it to take effect.

Comment: adding the path for easier access in the Terminal /System/Library/Components/CoreAudio.component/Contents/SharedSupport/SystemSounds
You only need to restart Finder (from the Force Quit Applications dialog).

Comment: 10.12.4 doesn't let me do this for some reason even when I'm logged in as root and prefix cp/mv/whatever with "sudo". Does anyone know what would be a good way to replace it? If it's safe, it would also be convenient if I could store the copy in the same folder as the original.